# Laravel: Order query by count id field on relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a resources table, and a resources_votes table in which I have a record for everytime a user likes [vote_id 1] or dislikes [vote_id 2] a resource. now I need to retrieve all the resource information ordered from most liked to the less one, and since resource has many resources_votes when I use `->with('votes')` it returns an array of objects with each one of the resources_votes related to the resource ID.

Is there a way I can count how many positive votes a resource has `[vote_id =2]`, add a field with this count and order the query from most voted to less voted?

PD: this is an example of a resource object with the `resources_votes`relationship, there you can see the votes array and the vote ID which I need to count and order according to:

```
    {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "aspernatur",
            "image": "http://lorempixel.com/480/480/?31738",
            "author": "Max Thiel",
            "created_by": 6,
            "reviewed_by": "Mr. Emiliano Frami",
            "lang_id": 2,
            "resource_type_id": 1,
            "status": "Borrado",
            "resource_type": "Imagen",
            "platforms": [],
            "classifications": [],
            "votes": [
              {
                "id": 2,
                "user_id": 2,
                "resource_id": 2,
                "vote_id": 1
              },
              {
                "id": 29,
                "user_id": 1,
                "resource_id": 2,
                "vote_id": 2
              },
              {
                "id": 24,
                "user_id": 12,
                "resource_id": 2,
                "vote_id": 1
              },
            ]
          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with eager loading like this

```
$resources = Resource::withCount(['votes' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('vote_id', '=', '2'); //count positive votes only
}])->get();
```

This will return a column named `votes_count`. You need to call that column to display the count.

Comment: is there a way i can retrieve both the positive and negative counts? I've tried to create two `withCount`but one overwrites the other. Is there a way to create a `votes_count` row and a `negative_votes_count` row?

Comment: I didn't know there is a use case "withCount" exist. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent Accessors.

Create the following custom field and function inside your model

```
protected $appends = ['positiveVotesCounter'];
```

Then, create the following function to retrieve your custom data.

```
function getPositiveVotesCounterAttribute() {
    $totalPositiveVotes = 0;
    foreach($this->votes as $vote) {
        if($vote['id'] == 2) {
            $totalPositiveVotes++;
        }
    }

    return $totalPositiveVotes;
}
```

More info can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators

Good luck!